# CustomAction on document library not visible

Tags: 2010, custom-actions

the scenario is the following
1. We have a site called meetings with 2 subsites for special meetings, Executive COmmitee, and Board of DIrectors
2. In each of those sites, a different meeting site is created when a meeting is created in the root site and the user executes a custom action.
3. In the newly created meeting subsites there is a document library called Agenda Points, which items are document sets.  I need to put a custom action there but I havent been able to.  The custom actions are not visible.

I tried with Type="ContentType", and List, I tried with multiple combinations but no success yet.

**The content type is called agenda point:**

```
 <ContentType ID="0x0120D52000D56C75F51E1BD54E9D59BBBA1925379A01" Name="$Resources:SPNLMeetings,ContentType_AgendaPoint_Name;"
```

**The Custom Action Elements.xml is:**

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CustomAction 
               RegistrationType="ContentType"
               RegistrationId="0x0120D52000D56C75F51E1BD54E9D59BBBA1925379A01"
               Location="EditControlBlock"
               ImageUrl="_layouts/images/workflows.gif"
               Sequence="5001"
               Rights="EditListItems"               Title="$Resources:SPNLMeetings,CustomAction_CopyAgendaPointToNextMeetingWithAttachments_Title_Open">
    <UrlAction Url="javascript:function process(){var site='{SiteUrl}';OpenPopUpPageWithTitle(site+'/_layouts/spnl.mtngs/CopyAgendaPointToNextMeetingWithAttachments.aspx?ListID={ListId}&amp;ID={ItemId}&amp;status=1.&amp;Source=' + window.location, RefreshOnDialogClose, 400, 200,'$Resources:SPNLMeetings,CustomAction_UpdateAgenda_Title_Open;');}; process();" />
  </CustomAction>     
    </Elements>
```

**The feature file, reduced.**

```
<Feature xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" ImageUrl="SPNL\spnl_feature.jpeg" Version="1.0.0.0" Title="$Resources:SPNLMeetings,Feature_NLMeetingsListDefinitions_Title" Description="$Resources:SPNLMeetings,Feature_NLMeetingsListDefinitions_Description" Id="374cd0fe-62b2-40b5-ba3a-a12fd200ec8b" Scope="Site">
  <ActivationDependencies>
    <ActivationDependency FeatureDescription="$Resources:SPNLMeetings,Feature_NLMeetingsContentTypes_Description" FeatureId="5d35f78b-2211-4cd8-bcba-6db7ac456b74" FeatureTitle="$Resources:SPNLMeetings,Feature_NLMeetingsContentTypes_Title" />
  </ActivationDependencies>
  <UpgradeActions>
    <VersionRange BeginVersion="0.0.0.0" EndVersion="0.9.9.9">
      <ApplyElementManifests>
        <ElementManifest Location="AgendaPointsList\CustomActions\Elements.xml" />
      </ApplyElementManifests>
    </VersionRange>
  </UpgradeActions>      
  <ElementManifests> 
    <ElementManifest Location="AgendaPointsList\CustomActions\Elements.xml" />
  </ElementManifests>
</Feature>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

**Update 1:**

By navigating to the 14 hive, I noticed that in the custom actions folder, there was an elements.xml file had nothing to do with the custom actions.

*I replace this line in the .spdata file*

```
<ProjectItemFile Source="CustomActions\Elements.xml" Target="AgendaPointsList\CustomActions\" Type="ElementManifest" />
```

Now I can see the customactions elements.xml file correctly in the 14 hive, but that didnt fix the issue anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might sound stupid, but is it possible that your issue could come from the incorrect Content Type used as your registration type said ContentType? Have you tried using simple as Id 0x01 (Document) or Library  as in

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CustomAction 
    Id="ECBItemCustomization"
    RegistrationType="List"
    RegistrationId="101"
    Location="EditControlBlock"
    Sequence="106"
    Title="Navigate to Site Settings">
    <UrlAction Url="/_layouts/Settings.aspx"/>
  </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

Otherwise you shouldn't fiddle with the .spdata files unless you what you are doing. Also check that your feature gets activated automatically upon deployment too.

Comment: I had already tried that, it didnt work, I tried again, it didnt work :(,

Comment: but I noticed something, the custom actions appear in the default document library ... I am close

Comment: the custom list registration id should be different: RegistrationId="10006"  damn!! 4 hours on this.